# Error: bytes-like object is required, not 'str' on pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following code to read the txt file as CSV

```
validationColumns='column1|column2'
headerColumns = validationColumns.split("|")
rawData = subprocess.check_output( 'sshpass -p \'pass\' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user tail -n +1 /var/prod/archive/new.txt | awk \'NR==1, NR==35\'', shell=True).decode('utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(rawData), encoding='utf8', sep='|', usecols=headerColumns, quotechar="~")
```

But I got the error like **bytes-like object is required, not 'str'** .
Can anyone please help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawData` isn't a `bytes` object. `check_output` returns one, but you immediately decoded it into a `str` object:

```
rawData = subprocess.check_output(...).decode('utf-8')
```

Just omit that method call.

Answer (score 1):

The result you receive from `check_output` is already text; there is no reason and no way to separately `decode` it.

To debug code like this, you want to successively remove code until the problem goes away; probably review the guidance to provide a [minimal reproducible example.](/help/mcve)

As an aside, you [really want to avoid the `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) and the pipe to Awk here. Python can perfectly well perform the same task, but if you run SSH anyway, you might as well refactor to use just Awk on the remote host.

```py
rawData = subprocess.check_output(
    ['sshpass', '-p', 'pass',
     'ssh', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'user',
     'awk', 'NR==2, NR==36', '/var/prod/archive/new.txt'])
```

The same Awk script would be simpler still with `sed`; `sed -n '2,36p'`